# implementing filter in a dynamic range in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have searched for this and found answers related to filters, and dynamic ranges separately, but could not figure how to put them together.

The structure of my excel sheet is:

- *Data*:

  - **Date        A B C**
  - 02-02-2012  a1  b1  c1
  - 07-07-2012  a2  b2  c2
- *Graphs*:

  - graphs generated on this sheet

I am using a named dynamic range *myDataRange* that returns only those rows whose data is equal to or greater than a particular reference date:

- =OFFSET(Data!$C$2,COUNTIF(Data!$B:$B,"<"&Graphs!$B$1&""),0,(COUNTA(Data!$C:$C)-1-COUNTIF(Data!$B:$B,"<"&Graphs!$B$1&"")),1)

On the graphs sheet I have entered a date in cell B1, for example : 05-05-2012

This would ensure myDataRange only returns the second row of data (whos date is 07-07-2012).
Out of this, I plot the column C.

Question: But now I also need the dynamic range to be filtered as per Column A. So if reference date is 05-05-2012 in graphs cell B1 and filter is a2, then myData range returns only one row. But if filter is 05-05-2012 and a1, then it would return 0 rows.

Could someone pls help with this - can I modify the dynamic range itself or would I have to implement this another way? I have tried to modify the dynamic range parameters, but I keep getting error messages, as it returns no values and then Excel can't graph it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried recording a Macro for Autofiltering? :)

Comment: @bonCodigo - hi, thanks for the suggestion. did not know about it. will look into it right now :)

Comment: @bonCodigo - looks like Autofilter might not work. but found an article on Advanced filter that might help with the date comparison.

Comment: @bonCodigo - silly me, Autofilter worked great. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: And if you are interested in please take a look at [this as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198098/excel-vba-apply-auto-filter-and-sort-by-specific-colour/14200175#14200175). It is just doing a sort and immitate the autofilter but doesn't hide the rows. IF you are interested in the future :)

Comment: Thanks, will see this. I don't know how to convert your comment into the answer, so pls change it if you could. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: it's alright. :) hey BTW you can answer your own question. Since I only wrote one comment to help you and you got everything else done, why don't you post the working piece of code that got you going :D If you do so, I'll give you a +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the range mentioned above, and the code below on a combobox I inserted on the sheet.

here is the code:

Sub DropDown2_Change()

```
Dim selectedVal As String

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs02").Shapes("Drop Down 2").ControlFormat
selectedVal = .List(.Value)
End With

'MsgBox selectedVal

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
.Select
.Range("A1:BY60000").Select

Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=selectedVal

End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs02").Select
```

End Sub

in this, the sheet on which I have put in the combobox (Drop Down 2) is sheet "graphs02".
The sheet Data has all my data, which is filtered according to the value selected in the combobox.

Again, I got most of this working with help of stackoverflow :)

Comment: AutoFilter will also work on a Range object e.g. .Range("A1:BY60000").AutoFilter Field:=CellIndex, Criteria1:=FilterValue '(CellIndex and FIlterValue being variables)