# Excel VBA - Apply auto filter and Sort by specific colour

Tags: sorting, excel, autofilter, vba

I have an auto-filtered range of data. The auto filter was created by the following VB code:

```
Sub Colour_filter()

Range("A4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

I would like to sort the values in column "A" (the data actually start from cell "A4") by the following colour ( Color = RGB(255, 102, 204) ) so all the cells with that colour sort to the top.

It would be fab if the extra code could be added to my existing code?

My office is really noisy and my VB isn’t the best. It is doubly hard with laughing, chatting ladies all about. Any help will be stress relief heaven!! (p.s. no poke at the ladies it’s just my office is 95% women).

---

Edited per request by @ScottHoltzman.

My requested code forms part of a larger code which would confuse matters, although here is a slimmed down version of the aspect I currently need.

```
Sub Colour_filter()
' Following code( using conditional formatting) adds highlight to 'excluded' courses based
'on 'course code' cell value matching criteria. Courses codes matching criteria are highlighted
'in 'Pink'; as of 19-Nov-2012 the 'excluded' course codes are
'(BIGTEST, BIGFATCAT).

' <====== CONDITIONAL FORMATTING CODE STARTS HERE  =======>
    Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
Formula1:="=""BIGTEST"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Color = 13395711
   End With

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
Formula1:="=""BIGFATCAT"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Color = 13395711

End With

' <====== CONDITIONAL FORMATTING CODE ENDS HERE  =======>

' Following code returns column A:A to Font "Tahoma", Size "8"
  Columns("A:A").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Tahoma"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 8
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone

     End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = False
    End With

' Following code adds border around all contiguous cells ion range, similar to using keyboard short cut "Ctrl + A".
Range("A4").Select
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select


With Selection
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With



' Following code adds 'Blue' cell colour to all headers in Row 4 start in Cell "A4".

 Range("A4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True

'<== adds auto-filter to my range of cells ===>

Range("A4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: If you [show us the code you've tried to get the sorting accomplished](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) you will get a lot more help a lot faster.

Comment: @moshjosh So regardless of the values, you just want to sort the range by `cell colour` ?

Comment: @moshjosh can you answer pleaes? and please attach a sample of column `A` into the question.

Comment: yes that's correct. @bonCodigo

Comment: @moshjosh have you seen [this](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/sort-by-color-in-excel-2003/)?

Comment: @moshjosh please take a look at the code provded and comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well here is a small `Sub` that does the following sorting as per shown image. Most of the values like dimensions/range sizes are very static since this is a sample. You may improve it to be dynamic. **Please comment if this code is going in the right direction** so I can update with the final sort.

**EDITTED CODE WITH DOUBLE SORT KYES**

code:
  Option Explicit

Sub sortByColor()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim inputArray As Variant, colourSortID As Variant
  Dim colourIndex As Long

```
Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("D2:D13")
colourIndex = Sheets(1).Range("G2").Interior.colorIndex

 ReDim inputArray(1 To 12)
 ReDim colourSortID(1 To 12)

For i = 1 To 12
    inputArray(i) = rng.Cells(i, 1).Interior.colorIndex
    If inputArray(i) = colourIndex Then
        colourSortID(i) = 1
    Else
        colourSortID(i) = 0
    End If
Next i

'--output the array with colourIndexvalues and sorting key values
 Sheets(1).Range("E2").Resize(UBound(inputArray) + 1) = _ 
                   Application.Transpose(inputArray)
 Sheets(1).Range("F2").Resize(UBound(colourSortID) + 1) = _ 
                   Application.Transpose(colourSortID)

 '-sort the rows based on the interior colour
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Set rng = rng.Resize(, 3)

    rng.Sort Key1:=Range("F2"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
    Key2:=Range("E2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you although this isn't what I needed. I want the cells which are Color = RGB(255, 102, 204); i.e Pink tombe sort so the all jump to the top.

Comment: What's given is a sample, so Set your own colour to sort either using either `RGB` or just index on the colour.

Comment: @moshjosh what I meant to say you can simply colour the `H2` cell by the `RGB` you need. Then Run the code I have given to you. This updated code is doing a `double sort` on two keys: `colourIndex` of each cell and another custom `index` assigned using your chosen `coloutIndex`. You can hide the column later if you wish to. I didn't mean to be harsh ;) So you may improve the code according to your constraints. Autofiltering is going to hide rows that do not match the colour. In this case everything is still shows well.