# VBA, COUNTIF, Exclude based on cell color

Tags: vba

I’m trying to count the number of “M”s and “F”s within column C but exclude cases where the cells interior color in column D (same row) is red.  The script is counting the number of cases of each “M” and “F” but not excluding any case where cell D is red. Any thoughts?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim F As Long
Dim M As Long
Dim colorD As Range
Dim Cell As Range


F = Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
M = Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Set colorD = Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)


If F < 2 Then F = 2
If M < 2 Then M = 2


For Each Cell In colorD
   If Cell.Interior.Color <> 3 Then
   F = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & F), "F")
   M = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & M), "M")
   End If
Next Cell

MsgBox ("Females=" & F & "," & "Males=" & M)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please do a debug print on this to see if the cell colourIndex is really `3`

```
Debug.Print Cell.Interior.ColorIndex
```

BECAUSE,

`Cell.Interior.Color` need a `RGB` to match... where as you just need the `.ColorIndex` to match ;) To be very precise `Color` supports more when `ColorIndex` supports limited number of colours. But Most likely in your case the `3` is not the colour of the `red` that you are trying to match..

So it has to be,

```
IF Cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> 3 then

//count count
End if
```

I tried out your sub: got few issues. I have put comments nexts to the code. Try the following out please.

1. Please use `Explicit reference for Ranges e.g.`Sheets(1).Range`it helps alot. So changed the way`Last Used Row` was found.
2. You were not setting up the `colorD` and it only had 2 rows. So changed it to,
       `Set colorD = Sheets(2).Range("D2").Resize(endRow)`
3. `If` is doing the opposite with `<>`, so changed it to  `If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then`
4. A typo changed it to  `M = M - redM`

Revised code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub countbyColourAndGender()
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim redF As Long
    Dim redM As Long
    Dim F As Long
    Dim M As Long
    Dim colorD As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim cellVal As String

    'Find the ending row --HERE: it gave an error, so changed it..
    endRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    'Ensure ending row is at least Row 2
    If endRow < 2 Then
        endRow = 2
    End If

    'Count all the Females
    F = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(2).Range("C2:C" & endRow), "F")
    'Count all the Males
    M = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(2).Range("C2:C" & endRow), "M")

    'Set the applicable Column D range -- HERE: changed using `Resize`
    Set colorD = Sheets(2).Range("D2").Resize(endRow)
    'Loop through each cell in Column D
    For Each Cell In colorD
        If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then '-- HERE: not <> but =
            'Red Cell found, get the cell value from Column C
            cellVal = LCase(Cell.Offset(-1, -1).Value)
            If cellVal = "f" Then redF = redF + 1 'Increment count of red Females
            If cellVal = "m" Then redM = redM + 1 'Increment count of red Males
        End If
    Next Cell

    'Subtract any red Females
    F = F - redF
    'Subtract any red Males : HERE it has to subsctract not equal..
    M = M - redM

    'Alert User with counts
    MsgBox ("Females=" & F & "," & "Males=" & M)
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @matt could you please give this a try... coz I happened to do something with [color indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198098/excel-vba-apply-auto-filter-and-sort-by-specific-colour/14200175#comment19690275_14200175) yesterday..so if not mistaken I couldn't use `.color`..

Comment: I changed the code to .ColorIndex. The change does nothing. a debug statement gives a value of 1. The cells color will be either "null", "black, "red", or "orange"

Comment: @matt I ran you code, please take a look at the revised version with proofs ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're re-evaluating your counts on every cell where the color is **not** red, instead of decrementing them.

```
For Each Cell In colorD
    If Cell.Interior.Color <> 3 Then
        'Here you are re-evaluating F, not incrementing it.
        F = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & F), "F")
        'And the same for M.
        M = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & M), "M")
    End If
Next Cell
```

I would evaluate your counts only once, and then keep track of red cells seperately (decrementing them from the counts as needed):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim redF As Long
    Dim redM As Long
    Dim F As Long
    Dim M As Long
    Dim colorD As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim cellVal As String

    'Find the ending row
    endRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).endRow
    'Ensure ending row is at least Row 2
    If endRow < 2 Then
        endRow = 2
    End If

    'Count all the Females
    F = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & endRow), "F")
    'Count all the Males
    M = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & endRow), "M")

    'Set the applicable Column D range
    Set colorD = Range("D2", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    'Loop through each cell in Column D
    For Each Cell In colorD
        If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            'Red Cell found, get the cell value from Column C
            cellVal = LCase(Cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value)
            If cellVal = "f" Then redF = redF + 1 'Increment count of red Females
            If cellVal = "m" Then redM = redM + 1 'Increment count of red Males
        End If
    Next Cell

    'Subtract any red Females
    F = F - redF
    'Subtract any red Males
    M = M = redM

    'Alert User with counts
    MsgBox ("Females=" & F & "," & "Males=" & M)
End Sub
```

Comment: it was couple of few changes I agree but not the re-evaluation part though... ;)

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this, had a meeting. After After some debugging on some errors that I had initially made I found that it works. Thank you both so much for your efforts!